# Bootstrap navbar styling issue in ASP.NET Core Web Application template

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Did anyone else notice that for the longest time there has been a bug in the _LoginPartial.cshtml of the ASP.NET Core Web Application template (w/ Individual User Accounts)?

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The navbar-right class being on both the form and ul elements causes a margin issue on the right side of the navbar where the text overflows to the right side of the screen. It is especially noticeable when you login and it says Hello [Users email]!

I believe the fix for this is to simply remove the navbar-right class from the form element. Everything still looks perfectly fine afterwards and the margin issue is resolved.

I would like to here what others think about this before reporting it as a bug. If there is a better fix for this, please share.